# Quicksort Pivot Points

Tags: java, quicksort

For quicksort, (in java, if it matters), is there a relationship between the number of pivot points (or pivot indices) and the size of a given array? For example, if the array size is 10, are there always going to be, say, 5 pivot points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, about n/2 is correct. However, I don't know why it would matter.

Comment: I have to (for an assignment) implement stacks into a quicksort program. The program has a partition method and a swap method that actually does the sorting but managing starting indices and size of the partitions created is what I have to do with stacks, before this assignment I would just do it recursively, but thats not an option now. This number is relevant to how long the while loop runs, inside of it I push, pop, and call the method partition, which is given, as stated above.

Comment: If you use the stack instead of recursion i.e. instead of the thread's stack, you stop when the stack is empty i.e. there is nothing more to do. The number of pivot point is like the numbers of leaves on a tree data structure when the size of the stack depends on the depth of the tree which is order log2(n). So I don't see how knowing the number of pivot points is useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could have how ever many pivots you want (up to n I suppose...)

The more pivots you have, the more efficient the next recursion will be, although if it were too large (especially if it were non-constant) you would lose more time finding your pivot than you would gain.

I believe the typical is 3 potential pivots per iteration, but it's entirely dependent on implementation.

But remember that in the worst case, you're going to end up with n iterations (quicksort's worst case is `O(n^2)`). That would naturally lend itself to requiring n pivots, and each iteration would do very little work.

Now, on the last iteration, you can expect about n/3 pivots. On the iteration above that, it would be n/6. On the next iteration it would be n/12. If you take the limit of that series, you end up with .6 repeating. So it looks like you can expect 2/3 n total pivots (because you'd have about 2/3 n total iterations)

Comment: I don't think 3 pivots would work (reliably, all of the time) on an array (of ints) size, say, 1000

Comment: @mcwillig You may end up with a bad iteration or two, but it (on average) sorts itself out on the next iteration. If you have 3 potential pivot points per iteration, then on the next iteration, you'd have 3 more on each side. So if one got small, oh well, it will just finish faster. As long as you typically split somewhere in half, you're good. You usually pick the median of the three.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. It depends on the data and your algorithm. On average with decently random data and a decent implementation it should be on the order of log<sub>2</sub>(n) pivots.